# Block function/fail if function called during static global initialization

Tags: c++, gcc

Is there anyway I can cause a function to fail if called during the initialization of a global static variable? The function uses another global static (from a different unit) and thus is unsafe to call during startup.

I have two reasons for this. The first is that if I could somehow detect this scenario I could print a useful debug message rather than having a segfault and wacky stack trace from it otherwise failing. Secondly I can prevent it from accidentally working. Sometimes the libraries and object files just line up right and the dependency orders are just fine, thus you think the code is correct, but it isn't.

Note: This is not a single program, but a libary function, so flagging some global variable as a first step to main *may* not be a workable option. To make matters worse, in one case it is actually a template function with references an extern static.

Note: For reasons of efficiency I wish to avoid the obvious solution of just wrapping the static in a function call.

*GCC trickery is allowed since detecting this on one of our platforms would be sufficient.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this :

```
#include <iostream>

bool& init()
{
    static bool inited=false;
    return inited;
}

class A
{
public:

    A()
    {
        if (! init())
        {
            std::cout<<"fail"<<std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout<<"ok"<<std::endl;
        }
    }

};

A a1;

int main()
{
    init() = true;
    A a2;
}
```

This will fail for global initialization, and pass for creating in main().

---

The above doesn't look nice, but there are no other ways, because (as you said in your question) the standard doesn't guarantee the order of initialization of objects before entering main. The only suggestion is to avoid creating objects before starting `main()`.

Comment: I do believe a flag in main would work, the problem is that many of these functions are in libraries and it would be difficult to coordinate setting the various flags.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y besides obvious "do not create global objects" I do not see other way

Comment: Confirmation that there is no other way is fine too (I don't expect miracles, just hope for them).